# Are object properties assigned in the same order they are declared?

Tags: javascript, function, properties

I have a JavaScript function that needs to return different objects depending on some variables.

```
return {
  source: fSource,
  a: readArray(),
  b: readArray()
};
```

Is there any guarantee that the interpreter assigns the first return value of readArray to a and the second to b? I could easily rewrite it to:

```
var tmp = {
  source: fSource,
};
tmp.a = readArray();
tmp.b = readArray();
return tmp;
```

But I have a lot of such code and the first notation is quite pretty.

I know that the order of object properties might change but I doubt this affects my case.

**Update:**

To clarify my concerns:

```
var a = {
  foo: fn1(),
  bar: fn2()
};
```

I don't care about the order of foo and bar in the object. But is it possible that fn2 is called before fn1?

Comment: This affects any cases in JavaScript objects. Initially object properties are not ordered and browsers may treat it differently. If you care of the order you'd better use array.

Comment: @VisioN I don't care about the order of properties, I care about the order of invocations.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. The order of invocations should be the same.

Comment: Potential duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437965/javascript-object-initialization-and-evaluation-order and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200387/are-javascript-object-properties-assigned-in-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Answering on your update...</sub>

### No, it is not possible.

The function invocations will go in the same order as you have declared in the code.